# Copying values to an excel sheet using openpyxl module

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy a bunch of titles I just scraped using soup to an excel sheet. There are 100 titles and I would like to copy all of them in the first column from A1:A100 using openpyxl.

```
#workbook already created in the same directory with python file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx') 
ws = wb.active

titles = soup.find_all("div", class_= "book-titles__info_clear")

for title in titles:
   all_titles = title.find("h3", class_ = "k-item__title")
   print(all_titles)
   #titles print fine in the console

for i in range("A1:A100"):
    ws[i] = all_titles
#this code only copies the last title in cell A2

wb.save('Book2.xlsx')
```

The exercise requires to specifically use openpyxl not csv, pandas, win32com.client, xlrd, xlsxwriter or other means. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all_titles = title.find("h3", class_ = "k-item__title")` - The code is assigning a variable inside loop. As a result this will always contain 1 item. When it comes to saving to worksheet, it will contain the last item.

Consider declaring an array outside the for loop and append to list.

**For example:**

```
all_titles = []

for title in titles:
    h3 = title.find("h3", class_ = "k-item__title")
    if h3:
       all_titles.append(h3.text.strip())
       print(h3.text.strip())
```

If you have an array and you want to append it as a single row (to Excel), then you can call `append()`

**For example:**

Replace this code:

```
for i in range("A1:A100"):
    ws[i] = all_titles
```

With:

```
ws.append(all_titles) # if all_titles is an array then items will append to multiple rows.

ws.append((all_titles)) # double brackets will append list to entire row or you can change all_titles to contain a nested array.
```

*(Your code is not runnable. Therefore I've not tested the example above, but should be good enough as an illustration)*

Comment: thank you for answering. It appends all the titles across the columns from A1 to .....BF1 Is there a solution to append across the rows from A1 to A100?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You just need double brackets ws.append((all_titles))